# Is it legal to pass lambda with an auto parameter to another function

Tags: c++, c++14

Is it legal to pass a lambda function with an auto parameter to another function? I mean if it's legal from c++ point of view, namely c++17.

I've tried doing so with clang, LLVM version 10.0.1 and it compiles but I understand that the auto parameter must be somehow deduced after the function that I pass the lambda to "sees" with what I want to call it.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename Fn>
void apply(Fn&& fn) {
    fn(std::string("string"));
    fn(10);
    fn(10.3);
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    apply([](auto&& arg){
        std::cout << arg << std::endl;
    });
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
string
10
10.3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A generic lambda generates an instance of a class that has an `operator()` template, but is not itself a template. Hence, that class type can be deduced without any issue.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense.